# Diferencias entre comentar con # y //

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en laravel y quisiera saber el uso adecuado de comentar con

```
1. #
```

O

```
 2. //
```

**Agradezco su ayuda**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Para hacer comentarios tienes las siguientes opciones, también te hago
>   la aclaración que esto que te muestro no tiene que ver directamente
>   con el framework Laravel si no mas bien con el lenguaje con el que
>   esta escrito por debajo que es PHP

Podemos observar que este estilo de comentario es heredado de C donde va a seguir ignorando código hasta que encuentre el siguiente signo `*/`

> útil para comentar bloques completos de código donde necesitas que sea
>   ignorada una determinada cantidad de código por ejemplo donde
>   encuentres funciones o clases completas de código

**Comentario multilinea**

```
/*
   $name1 = "hola";
   $name2 = "hi";
*/
```

**Comentario de una sola línea**

Este estilo de comentarios se heredó de C++ de una sola línea y se observa de manera mas común para comentar líneas solas de código dentro de scripts o archivos que por ejemplo en este caso terminen en extensión **.php**

```
//$name1 = "Hola";
```

**Comentar una sola línea de código con #**

Este tipo de comentarios es mas al estilo de comentar código desde la *consola/terminal/cmd* e igualmente solo me sirve para comentar una sola línea de código

```
#$name1 = "Hola";
```